# Can the blog width be dynamic on Blogger?

Tags: css, blogger, layout

I see that Blogger will let you set the blog width under Overview-> Template Designer->Adjust Widths.

However, this seems to be a fixe width - is there an easy way to set a max and a min width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to set a fluid width, an example blogspot blog is here http://vinfirst.blogspot.com/ and here http://bloggeruniversity.blogspot.com/2006/08/fluid-3-column-blogger-template.html

Google for "blogspot fluid width" or "blogspot width percentage"